# NLog not sending to papertrail once deployed to an EC2

Tags: c#, nlog

When deploying to my EC2 NLog no longer seems to be working correctly. When deployed locally, I have no issues logging the chat. On the other hand, it's rapidly writing to it's internal log and ignoring the value of if it should write to it's internal log at all.

I've tried switching the protocol type to be used from TCP to UDP, which stops it from writing errors (but also does not allow it to connect to PaperTrail which was the point). I've also tried turning off internal logging, which also does not work. Recopying over my NLog.config, as well as going through the initial tutorial multiple times. I've also checked my firewall settings for ports, the EC2 security group settings for ports, and the application permissions on the firewall.

**NLog version**: "4.6.2"

**Platform**:.Net 4.5

**Current NLog config** (xml or C#, if relevant)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="false" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.Syslog" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="syslog" type="Syslog">
      <messageCreation>
        <facility>Local7</facility>
          <rfc5424 hostname="${machinename}-Ragnarok" appName="ChatServer-Ragnarok" />

      </messageCreation>
      <messageSend>
        <protocol>TCP</protocol>
        <tcp>
          <server>logs.papertrailapp.com</server>
          <port>REDACTED</port>
          <tls>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </tls>
        </tcp>
      </messageSend>
    </target>

    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />

  </targets>

  <rules>
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" appendTo="syslog" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The actual error is as follows (It's repeated every few seconds in the logs): 
2019-04-15 13:35:22.3986 Warn SendAsync failed Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NLog.Targets.Syslog.MessageSend.SocketInitializationForWindows.KeepAliveConfigurationIsUpToDate(KeepAliveConfig keepAliveConfig)
   at NLog.Targets.Syslog.MessageSend.SocketInitializationForWindows.ApplyKeepAliveValues(Socket socket, KeepAliveConfig keepAliveConfig)
   at NLog.Targets.Syslog.MessageSend.SocketInitialization.SetKeepAlive(Socket socket, KeepAliveConfig keepAliveConfig)
   at NLog.Targets.Syslog.MessageSend.Tcp.Init()
   at NLog.Targets.Syslog.MessageSend.MessageTransmitter.b__21_0(Task _)
   at NLog.Targets.Syslog.Extensions.TaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<Then>b__0(Task t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work / why it's not working when deployed?

Comment: First the the TCP keep-alive is being received which is a message length with zero data bytes.  So you need to ignore the zero length messages.  It looks like you are failing when you are trying to Send() the zero length received message.

Comment: It would be hard to tell without knowing the AWS Setup.  Does a small test program work to make sure it is not a configuration issue with AWS?  Do the Ephermeral Ports need to be open and if so are they?

Comment: @JAZ So ports outbound and inbound work, I've also set up nxlog, which is using the same port and is already posting correctly to Papertrail without an issue.

Comment: Good idea @jdweng, I'll check that out now!

Answer (score 0):

Just a stopgap for now just to add the following to the config, which allows it to not crash on the "Keep Alive"

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="false" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.Syslog" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="syslog" type="Syslog">
      <messageCreation>
        <facility>Local7</facility>
          <rfc5424 hostname="${machinename}-Ragnarok" appName="ChatServer-Ragnarok" />

      </messageCreation>
      <messageSend>
        <protocol>TCP</protocol>
        <tcp>
          <server>logs.papertrailapp.com</server>
          <port>REDACTED</port>
          <tls>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </tls>
          <keepAlive>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <time>15</time>
          </keepAlive>
        </tcp>
      </messageSend>
    </target>

    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />

  </targets>

  <rules>
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" appendTo="syslog" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The code I've added in question is the following:

```
<keepAlive>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <time>15</time>
</keepAlive>
```

Edit: 
A fix was just pushed to NLog.Targets.Syslog's git which fixed this issue for me entirely. 
https://github.com/luigiberrettini/NLog.Targets.Syslog/pull/183